# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. Error

Tags: php, laravel, put

Hello i am trying to edit my reservation through the web I am pretty new to laravel I keep getting the same error I think it has to do with my routes.
when i click submit button for update The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. show up

how i can fix it?

this is the error exception MethodNotAllowedHttpException

here is my code
web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Reservationcontroller;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});


// Admin Dashoard
Route::get('admin', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});

// Reservation Controller
Route::get('admin/reservation/{id}/delete',[Reservationcontroller::class, 'destroy']);
Route::resource('admin/reservation',Reservationcontroller::class);
```

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\models\Reservation;
class Reservationcontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data=Reservation::all(); //show data in reservation page
        return view('reservation.index',['data'=>$data]); 
        //pass data in reservation page

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('reservation.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data= new Reservation;
        $data->date=$request->date;
        $data->name=$request->name;
        $data->description=$request->description;
        $data->invoicenumber=$request->invoicenumber;
        $data->passengerid=$request->passengerid;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('admin/reservation/create')->with('success','Reservation has been added.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $data=Reservation::find($id); //find reservation
        return view('reservation.show',['data'=>$data]); 
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $data=Reservation::find($id); //find reservation
        return view('reservation.edit',['data'=>$data]);

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data=Reservation::find($id);
        $data->date=$request->date;
        $data->name=$request->name;
        $data->description=$request->description;
        $data->invoicenumber=$request->invoicenumber;
        $data->passengerid=$request->passengerid;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('admin/reservation/'.$id.'/edit')->with('success','Reservation data has been updated.'); 
        
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- DataTales Example -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Edit Reservation
             <a href="{{url('admin/reservation')}}" class="float-right btn btn-success btn-sm">View All Reservation</a> 
         </h6>
     </div>
     <div class="card-body">
        @if(Session::has('success'))
        <p class="text-success">{{session('success')}}</p>
        @endif
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <form method="POST" action="{{url('admin/reservation/'.$data->id)}}">
                @csrf                
                @method('put')
                <table class="table table-bordered" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <td><input value="{{$data->date}}" name="date" type="datetime-local" class="form-controll" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <td><input value="{{$data->name}}" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <td><textarea name="description" class="form-control">{{$data->description}}</textarea></td>

                <tr>
                    <th>InvoiceNumber</th>
                    <td><input value="{{$data->invoicenumber}}" name="invoicenumber" type="number" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>PassengerID</th>
                    <td><input value="{{$data->passengerid}}" name="passengerid" type="number" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">  
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->

@endsection
```

This is route list

```
 GET|HEAD        / ..................................................................................................
  POST            _ignition/execute-solution ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionContr…
  GET|HEAD        _ignition/health-check ....... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
  POST            _ignition/update-config .... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
  GET|HEAD        admin ..............................................................................................
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation .................................. reservation.index › Reservationcontroller@index
  POST            admin/reservation .................................. reservation.store › Reservationcontroller@store
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/create ......................... reservation.create › Reservationcontroller@create
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/{id}/delete ........................................ Reservationcontroller@destroy
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/{reservation} ...................... reservation.show › Reservationcontroller@show
  PUT|PATCH       admin/reservation/{reservation} .................. reservation.update › Reservationcontroller@update
  DELETE          admin/reservation/{reservation} ................ reservation.destroy › Reservationcontroller@destroy
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/{reservation}/edit ................. reservation.edit › Reservationcontroller@edit
  GET|HEAD        api/user ...........................................................................................
  GET|HEAD        sanctum/csrf-cookie .................................... Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
```

Comment: run artisan command php artisan route:list to list your routes and then share routes here

Comment: Okay, done i am pretty sure the problem is with the routes

Comment: did you check form action by inspecting form from in browser.

Answer (score 0):

resource creates your routes will be like this.

```
   route::get('admin/reservation',Reservationcontroller@index);
    route::get('admin/reservation/create',Reservationcontroller@create);
    route::post('admin/reservation/store',Reservationcontroller@store)
    route::get('admin/reservation/{id}',Reservationcontroller@show);
    route::get('admin/reservation/{id}/edit',Reservationcontroller@edit);
    route::put('admin/reservation/{id}',Reservationcontroller@update)
    route::delete('admin/reservation/{id}',Reservationcontroller@destroy)
```

In the blade file use the route by below.

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{url('admin/reservation/'.[$data->id])}}">
                
   @csrf   
   @method("PUT")
 </form>
```

Comment: Still having the same error i tried everything.