# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. Error

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I am trying to edit my reservation through the web I am pretty new to Laravel I keep getting the same error I think has to do with my route.
when I click submit button for update The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. show up

how I can fix it?

this is the error exception MethodNotAllowedHttpException

here is my code
web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Reservationcontroller;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});


// Admin Dashoard
Route::get('admin', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});

// Reservation Controller
Route::get('admin/reservation/{id}/delete',[Reservationcontroller::class, 'destroy']);
Route::resource('admin/reservation',Reservationcontroller::class);
```

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\models\Reservation;
class Reservationcontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data=Reservation::all(); //show data in reservation page
        return view('reservation.index',['data'=>$data]); 
        //pass data in reservation page

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('reservation.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data= new Reservation;
        $data->date=$request->date;
        $data->name=$request->name;
        $data->description=$request->description;
        $data->invoicenumber=$request->invoicenumber;
        $data->passengerid=$request->passengerid;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('admin/reservation/create')->with('success','Reservation has been added.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $data=Reservation::find($id); //find reservation
        return view('reservation.show',['data'=>$data]); 
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $data=Reservation::find($id); //find reservation
        return view('reservation.edit',['data'=>$data]);

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data=Reservation::find($id);
        $data->date=$request->date;
        $data->name=$request->name;
        $data->description=$request->description;
        $data->invoicenumber=$request->invoicenumber;
        $data->passengerid=$request->passengerid;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('admin/reservation/'.$id.'/edit')->with('success','Reservation data has been updated.'); 
        
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is edit.blade.php

```xml
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- DataTales Example -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Edit Reservation
                <a href="{{url('admin/reservation')}}" class="float-right btn btn-success btn-sm">View All Reservation</a> 
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @if(Session::has('success'))
                <p class="text-success">{{session('success')}}</p>
            @endif
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <form method="POST" action="{{url('admin/reservation/'.$data->id)}}">
                    @csrf                
                    @method('put')
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <td>
                                <input value="{{$data->date}}" name="date" type="datetime-local" class="form-controll" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <td>
                                <input value="{{$data->name}}" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>    
                        <tr>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <td>
                                <textarea name="description" class="form-control">{{$data->description}}</textarea>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                            <th>InvoiceNumber</th>
                            <td>
                                <input value="{{$data->invoicenumber}}" name="invoicenumber" type="number" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>PassengerID</th>
                            <td>
                                <input value="{{$data->passengerid}}" name="passengerid" type="number" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
@endsection
```

This is the route list

```
 GET|HEAD        / ..................................................................................................
  POST            _ignition/execute-solution ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionContr…
  GET|HEAD        _ignition/health-check ....... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
  POST            _ignition/update-config .... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
  GET|HEAD        admin ..............................................................................................
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation .................................. reservation.index › Reservationcontroller@index
  POST            admin/reservation .................................. reservation.store › Reservationcontroller@store
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/create ......................... reservation.create › Reservationcontroller@create
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/{id}/delete ........................................ Reservationcontroller@destroy
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/{reservation} ...................... reservation.show › Reservationcontroller@show
  PUT|PATCH       admin/reservation/{reservation} .................. reservation.update › Reservationcontroller@update
  DELETE          admin/reservation/{reservation} ................ reservation.destroy › Reservationcontroller@destroy
  GET|HEAD        admin/reservation/{reservation}/edit ................. reservation.edit › Reservationcontroller@edit
  GET|HEAD        api/user ...........................................................................................
  GET|HEAD        sanctum/csrf-cookie .................................... Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
```

Comment: You asked about this an hour ago already, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71393944/1427878 Please do not delete questions, only to ask the same thing again. You had already gotten some feedback to your original question - even if that did not lead to the solution, that feedback is now simply lost to anyone else reading this new question here. So someone else might now be tempted to suggest the exact same thing that already has been suggested, a second time.

Comment: Are you tried: `php artisan route:cache` ?

Answer (score 1):

Resource gives you these routes (with user as example):

```
Verb          Path                        Action  Route Name
GET           /users                      index   users.index
GET           /users/create               create  users.create
POST          /users                      store   users.store
GET           /users/{user}               show    users.show
GET           /users/{user}/edit          edit    users.edit
PUT|PATCH     /users/{user}               update  users.update
DELETE        /users/{user}               destroy users.destroy
```

Your problem is that in your blade file action url is missing the wildcard ({user} in above example), therefore it's calling the wrong url.

Comment: what is the correct URL if you do not mind me asking. I only started 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `route` helper in your form tag.

```xml
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('reservations.update', [$data->id]) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('put')
    ...
</form>
```

Make sure your `$data` is valid. If `$data` is an instance of a `Model` class, you can pass it directly.

```php
route('reservations.update', [$data])
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases the problem solved by using: `php artisan route:cache`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Form `action=` attribute to the next one

```
{{ route('reservation.update', ['reservation' => $data->id]) }}
```

More information about [route binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Same as for the first response: Check that the url in your blade

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{url('admin/reservation/'.$data->id)}}">
```

is correctly rendere. A PUT method towards an URL without any resource generates the error you see.